# How to center the window in xfce?

Tags: xfce, window-manager

In **openbox** I can easily bind a hotkey `Alt-c` or `Win-c` to center the current window. How can I do the same in **xfce** window manager? I could only find the commands to tile windows left/right.

Comment: I think it would either need to be the setting in Window Manager Tweaks > Placement to center at window launch (slide it all the way to the right) or maybe you could implement an `xdotool` script to center via a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/104155/center-a-window-via-command-line#answer-571711